# Как вывести информацию о нагрузке сервера?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Здравствуйте, у меня два вопроса.

- Вопрос первый - вот "гулял" по интернету и увидел следующие. На одном сайте в низу его страницы была информации как загрузка сайта грузит систему. Там было написано процент и оперативную память какую он берет на себя (там было около 22 мб). К сожалению, ссылку куда-то дел и не могу найти куда. Суть вопроса, есть ли такие функции в php, которые показывает нагрузку, или они через `microtime()` сделали условие, при котором будет от 1-100% показываться?
- Второй вопрос: видел, что только в классах объявляют переменную (БЕЗ УКАЗАНИЕ ТИПА), нельзя ли как-то сделать так, чтобы указывать тип изначально, как на языке С++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.1. [Средняя загрузка процессора](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sys-getloadavg.php). В комментариях вроде есть аналог для серверов на WIN.
1.2. [Пик выделенной памяти](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) под ПШП, работает только в *никс.
2. PHP не типизированный язык, задавать типы в нем нельзя.